# SSRS Report from a PIVOT query with unknown number of columns

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services, pivot

I have a PIVOT query that is returning an unknown number of dynamic columns. So the query will return something like

ID | Col1 | Col2 | ..... | ColN

ID is the only static column and the rest are all dynamic. The number and the names of the columns are unknown.

How can I write a report in SSRS that can handle this? Any tips and direction will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSRS will not be able to handle your pivot table because the columns are not known at design time. SSRS has feature called `Matrix` that will handle the pivot a run time based off run time data if your design time structure is static.

```
ID | ColumnName | Value
------------------------
1  | Colu1      | Value1
1  | Colu2      | Value2
2  | Colu2      | Value2
```

I would recommend that you return detail rows from TSQL and allow SSRS to handle the pivot. This will allow for one stored procedure to be used for multiple SSRS reports and aggregations instead of the single aggregation provide by `PIVOT`.

To save on duplicate processing, `Matrix` will also handle the sorting so no need to sort inside of TSQL.

Reference: [Create a Matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/create-a-matrix-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: So currently my query returns data in the form I listed above. You want me to write a query in the format -  ID | Column | Value and then use a matrix in SSRS?

Comment: SSRS does a wonderful job at runtime pivot tables. Yes, I would write the query with the above structure and use a matrix.

Comment: Ok I wrote the query to get the data in the following format. However I need one little change.

The query is 

    select distinct pApps.ApplicationID, ppl.LastName As ColName, isnull(ev.AnswerNumeric, 0) as ColValue
    from pApps inner join ev on pApps.SomeColumn = ev.SomeColumn
 inner join ppl on pApps.SomeColumn = ppl.SomeColumn 
    Order By ApplicationID

I need to add a total column as well. 

The data is coming out as

ApplicationID | ColName | ColValue
12 | A | 5
12| B | 9
14 | A | 12
14 | B | 3

I need to add a total for each application that is the sum of A & B

Comment: @JackSmith SSRS `Matrix` has the ability to create a total row for you. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-a-total-to-a-group-or-tablix-data-region-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017)